# Adding conditionals in Packer provisioners?

Tags: packer

Is there a sane way to add a conditional inside of a packer provisioner? Something to the effect of:

```
$ packer build -var "debug=true" build.json


"provisioners": [{
  "type": "puppet-masterless",
  "execute_command": "{{ if eq `debug` "true" }} strace {{ end }} {{ .FacterVars }} puppet apply --verbose --detailed-exitcodes --modulepath='/tmp/manifests/modules' {{ .ManifestFile }}",
  "facter": {},
  "manifest_dir": "../manifests",
  "manifest_file": "../manifests/vagrant/nocm.pp",
  "module_paths": [
    "../manifests/modules/external"
  ]
}],
"variables": {
  "debug":    "false",
}
```

Where execute command contains

```
{{ if eq `debug` "true" }} strace {{ end }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try to add your variable in the `provisioner` part :

**NOTE** : I did not test it myself but use that for normal shell provisioner

```
"provisioners": [{
  "environment_vars": [
    "DEBUG={{user `debug`}}",
  ]
  "type": "puppet-masterless",
  "execute_command": "{{ if eq .DEBUG "true" }} strace {{ end }} {{ .FacterVars }} puppet apply --verbose --detailed-exitcodes --modulepath='/tmp/manifests/modules' {{ .ManifestFile }}",
  "facter": {},
  "manifest_dir": "../manifests",
  "manifest_file": "../manifests/vagrant/nocm.pp",
  "module_paths": [
    "../manifests/modules/external"
  ]
}],
"variables": {
  "debug":    "false",
}
```